# Applying for Family Re Union for Italy while in Italy

Tags: resident-permit, indian-citizens, family, paperwork

I am an Indian. I came alone to Italy for work with proper work permit valid for around a year.
Now I want to take my wife and child along with me. I am planning to take a tourist Visa for them and after they come to Italy, I would like to apply for Family Reunion so that they don't go back after 90 days validity of tourist Visa.

Is this possible? I have applied for Residence Permit (permisso di soggiorno) for myself and it may take three months to get that and apply for Family Reunion.

What are the documents I have to prepare for Family Reunion before they travel to Italy as a tourist?

Answer (score 2):

Just to update for others who might seek this info.

I was able to bring my family on a tourist visa, and apply for residence permit in Italy. I already had a residence permit for myself.

Once your family is in Italy on a short term visa, and if they dont want to go back leaving you, then you can apply for the residence permit for the spouse.

Mandatory before your spouse come to Italy is the legalized and translated marriage certificate at the Italy consulate in home country.